# Sending a Request To a database(google sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, get, xmlhttprequest

I have created a script within google sheets. It gives a result of a cell from my table in google sheets(kinda database). I want the result send to my html page, and i have tried  so far with XMLHttprequest but with no success.

What have i done wrong?

Here is the [Script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5RzvUWSEOjerJpouxN72wpsgpsF8IWQo2AvjZUdRPcqskz28/exec)

```js
<script>
function load() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5RzvUWSEOjerJpouxN72wpsgpsF8IWQo2AvjZUdRPcqskz28/exec", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Members:</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="load()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: I used some of the code u posted. But unfortunately, have I solved the problem by my self. Thank u :)

Comment: Nice, glad to hear you got it solved! If you don't consider my answer as the correct answer to your question you can write your own and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read a spreadsheet from google:

- download a script called [Tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) and add it to your HTML. (The readme is [here](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/commit/55ba0808a2863cbac3d1cfd73e6899ecfdcd7779))
- In Google Docs go up to the `File` menu and pick `Publish to the web`. Then click `Start publishing`. A URL will appear, something like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html`, that is the URL you will use.
- Then call it with this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var public_spreadshseet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?YOUR_URL_HERE';
  
  // YOUR_URL_HERE sample: hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html
  // You get this URL from google docs after you publish the spreadsheet


  function init() 
  {
      Tabletop.init(
      { 
          key: public_spreadshseet_url,
          callback: showInfo,
          simpleSheet: true
      })
  }
  
  // This function gets called to give output
  function showInfo(data)
  {
      alert("Successfully processed!")
      console.log(data);           <-- Here is the spreadsheet data
  }  
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Members:</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="init()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```